# Can't save entity in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have created simple CRUD service. With 4 entities: Customer, Provider, Product, Deal.

`Customer` and `Provider` entities has composed id `AppId` with the following structure:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppId implements Serializable {
    private String app;
    private String id;
    //...
}
```

Here is business logic I want:
Providers entity cascades and creates Product entities.
When the customer makes deal with provider I need to create entity `Deal`, which doesn't cascade any other entities.
It just has fields which refer to provider, customer and product of the deal.

I created some providers and customers.
Then I tried to create deal, but I got fields customer and provider `null`.

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Here are my entities definitions:

---

`Provider`:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "provider")
public class Provider implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "appid")
    private AppId appId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;

    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private float longitude;

    @Column(name = "work_date")
    private Date workDate;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "provider_product"
            , joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "provider_app"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
            }
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id"))
    private Set<Product> products;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "app", referencedColumnName = "app", updatable = false, insertable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    })
    private List<Deal> dealList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

---

`Customer`:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @Column(name = "appid")
    private AppId appId;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    public Customer(AppId appId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.appId = appId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

---

`Product`:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private long cost;
}
```

---

`Deal`:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "deal")
public class Deal implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "provider_app", referencedColumnName = "app", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Provider provider;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "customer_app", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "deal_product"
            , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="deal_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="product_id", insertable = false, updatable = false))
    private Set<Product> product;

    // deal is complete when provider entered deal id
    @Column(name = "closed")
    private boolean closed = false;
}
```

Comment: why do you have `insertable = false` for `provider` and `customer` fields in `Deal` entity?

Comment: @harsh because when creating `deal` entity you can't create new `provider` or `customer`. `deal` could only be created when there are `provider` and `customer` created before.

Comment: please share your code where you create and save a deal, its difficult to say anything without looking at that

Comment: @harsh link to project: https://github.com/oybek/shavuha-CRUD/tree/master/src/main/java/com/oybek/shavuha

Answer (score 1):

By removing `insertable = false` for `customer` and `provider` fields in the `Deal` entity, everything works fine.

```
    {
    "id": 5,
    "provider": {
        "appId": {
            "app": "vk",
            "id": "123"
        },
        "name": null,
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "workDate": null,
        "products": null,
        "dealList": []
    },
    "customer": {
        "appId": {
            "app": "vk",
            "id": "123"
        },
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null
    },
    "product": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Temp",
            "cost": 100
        }
    ],
    "closed": false
}
```

I could get the following response.

`insertable = false` on a field means when you are saving the entity you won't be saving the value for that field and will set the field explicitly somewhere.

`insertable = true` doesn't mean you will create a new `Customer` or `Provider`, that is handled by `CascadeType`

Comment: it rewrites provider entity when creating deal that is not correct